# Pyplot grid with different linewidths

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

i want to show a grid with different linewidths with pyplot, here is the context:

Cells do not communicate with each other. They are separated by
walls of different thicknesses (there are 5 different wall thicknesses).[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw0r5.png)

Thanks for helping

i tried this :

```
rows, cols = self.lignes, self.colonnes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols,
                       sharex='col',
                       sharey='row')

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        ax[row, col].text(0.5, 0.5,
                          str((row, col)),
                          color="green",
                          fontsize=18,
                          ha='center')
        plt.axis('on')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to choose your spine width for each subplot, but here's how to set the width:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows, cols = 2, 3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols,
                       sharex='col',
                       sharey='row')

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        spine_proxy = ax[row, col].spines[['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']]
        spine_proxy.set_linewidth(row*cols+col+1)
        ax[row, col].text(0.5, 0.5,
                          str((row, col)),
                          color="green",
                          fontsize=18,
                          ha='center')
        plt.axis('on')

plt.show()
```

For more information about Matplotib's API for the spines, see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html).